# What does [&] mean in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I saw a piece of code like this:

```
Foo(
  [&](int a){
    ...
  }
);
```

Seems like an inner function, but why there is a `[&]`?

Comment: Looks like passing a lambda function with a capture to foo...http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Comment: Read about [anonymous functions (also known as lambda functions/expressions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29).

Comment: It's for C++11 lambda expressions.  More information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), the `[&]` means that:

> captures all automatic variables mentioned in the body of the lambda by reference